# Parsing JSON String with json2.asp KEY Values

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to parse this JSON string -

```js
{
   "Success": true,
   "Messages": [],
   "LeadInfo": {
      "LeadID": "21941873",
      "CapturedDate": "4/29/2015 9:39:33 AM",
      "CapturedBy": "Dev Kit 15231929",
      "ConnectKey": "1001",
      "FirstName": "DEMO_1001",
      "LastName": "ATTENDEE_1001",
      "Title": "",
      "Company": "DEMOCOMPANY_1001",
      "Company2": "",
      "Address": "145861 N Market Street",
      "Address2": "",
      "Address3": "",
      "City": "Frederick",
      "StateCode": "MD",
      "ZipCode": "21701",
      "CountryCode": "United States",
      "Email": "1001@experient-inc.com",
      "Phone": "1234567890",
      "PhoneExtension": "1111",
      "Fax": "9876543210",
      "Notes": ""
   },
   "Demographics": [
      {
         "Key": "CATEGORY",
         "Description": "Category/Classification",
         "Value": "Educator"
      },
      {
         "Key": "SPECIALTY",
         "Description": "Specialty",
         "Value": "General"
      },
      {
         "Key": "ADDTYPECODE",
         "Description": "ADDRESS TYPE",
         "Value": ""
      }
   ]
}
```

I am able to get all of the values using this -

```
Dim Att: Set Att = JSON.parse(API_Response)

Att.LeadInfo.get("FirstName")
Att.LeadInfo.get("LastName")
```

This works great.

My issue is how do I get the Values inside the Demographics Piece. What I am trying to get is the value "Educator" from the CATEGORY KEY.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like `Demographics` is an array of objects so you would need to loop through them probably with a `For Each` loop. Something like `For Each demo In att.Demographics` then you can reference inside the loop `demo.Key` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Demographics` object appears to be an Array of objects. You should be able to loop through using a `For Each` loop to enumerate the objects in turn and check for the specific `Key`.

```vb
Dim demo, key, desc, val
'...
For Each demo In Att.Demographics
  key = demo.Get("Key")
  desc = demo.Get("Description")
  val = demo.Get("Value")
  If key = "CATEGORY" Then Exit For
Next
```

*<sup>`...` - denotes assumed code</sup>*